# Proof that adding some quantity of stocks in a portfolio of option does not change the portfolio Gamma

Tags: options, greeks, proof

I would like to proof mathematically and intuitively that adding some quantity of underlying to a portfolio of option does not change the overall gamma.
Can you help me?

Comment: Intuitively, and considering you are not talking about options on options, the underlying would have delta of 1 and gamma of 0 since it has no optionality. So no matter what quantity of the underlying you add to the portfolio, the change in delta for a change in the price of the underlying (gamma) will remain the same.

Comment: Could it be because the second derivative of the underlying with respect to the underlying is zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

overall gamma is second derivative of whole portfolio over underlying.
adding any function (such as underlying*constant) which second derivative is 0 does not alter overall second derivative.